# Antlr4 import of combined grammar failing

Tags: import, antlr4

I am presently getting...

```
error(56): AqlCommentTest.g4:12:4: reference to undefined rule: htmlCommentDeclaration
error(56): AqlCommentTest.g4:13:4: reference to undefined rule: mdCommentDeclaration
```

The import for the lexer grammar does seem to be loading.
The following files present the problem.

AqlCommentTest.g4

```
grammar AqlCommentTest;
import AqlLexerRules;
import AqlComment;

program: commentDeclaration+;

commentDeclaration:
    htmlCommentDeclaration     #Comment_HTML
  | mdCommentDeclaration       #Comment_MD
;
```

AqlComment.g4

```
grammar AqlComment;
import AqlLexerRules;

htmlCommentDeclaration: 'html' '{' '(*' STRING '*)' '}';

mdCommentDeclaration: 'md' '{' '(*' STRING '*)' '}';
```

AqlLexerRules.g4

```
lexer grammar AqlLexerRules;
STRING :  '"' [a-z]? '"' ;
```

The errors can be stopped by removing the 'import AqlLexerRules;' from the 'AqlCommentTest.g4' file.

Why does this "fix" the problem?

How can I check to see if and how an antlr4 import statement is actually applied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the import lexer rules comes last :

```
import AqlComment;
import AqlLexerRules;
```

the error changes to :

```
error(54): AqlCommentTest.g4:4:0: repeated grammar prequel spec (options, tokens, or import); please merge
```

Hence the question : is there a constraint about import ?

In the [Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) 15.2 Grammar Structure or [doc](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md) you can find :

> There can be at most one each of options, imports, and token specifications.

If I change the import to :

```
import AqlComment, AqlLexerRules;
```

it compiles.